# Update or Overwrite in SQL Automation when using Contact Data Attribute Group in Journey?

Tags: journeybuilder, sql, automationstudio, contactbuilder, attribute-group

I have a Journey using Attribute Group / Contact Data.

**ContactKey:1:N**

The Journey Entry data extension (:1) in the Attribute Group, has a Today minus -2 days filtering in the SQL query in Automation Studio. The SQL query activity has 'Overwrite' data action method.

The second DE (:N) has no SQL date filtering and is using 'Overwrite' too.

The automation runs every hour, as we expect the data to change, which will be used for wait and decision splits in the journey.

The contacts that enter the journey on Today -2 days that no longer meet the criteria after entering the journey (for example when they become Today - 7days)  will be removed from the Entry DE if using 'Overwrite'.

Will they still be processed in the Journey? Or will they be removed from the Journey?

If they still remain in the journey, will their Decision Splits using the Contact Data still work as intended? Specifically, if using Contact Data from the :N DE?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your contacts previously injected into the Journey would continue in the Journey, even though they no longer qualify for entry criteria, unless you've defined Exit Criteria for the Journey.

Decision Splits based on Contact Data use data as it is at the time of evaluation, not as it was at the time of entry. Decision Splits based on Journey Data evaluate data as it was at the time of entry.

Be cautious about Decision Split logic based on 1:N relationships. For example, suppose your 1:N is Order:LineItems. A decision based on "LineItem.ProductType != 'Shoes'" would evaluate to "true", even though there was a "Shoe" in one of the multiple LineItems associated with the Order. It's about semantics.

Comment: Thanks Macca, since the contact will still remain in the journey, which Contact Data would the journey use for the decision splits? As that record will no longer exist in the DEs powering the attribute group. Will it use Journey data?

re: your 2nd point, so the decision split only evaluates the first record JB finds for the split criteria?

Comment: You explicitly choose whether your decisions are based on Journey or Contact data. Journey data's just the data you injected - a row. That's immutable, it doesn't change. Contact data's ephemeral and decisions based on Contact data are evaluated on whatever's there at the time of the decision. If your decision finds one record, based on 1:N, it's "true".